# wpf mvvm dealing with collection properties in ViewModel and the propagation of their values into the Model

Tags: c#, wpf, design-patterns, mvvm, binding

A property in `ViewModel`, that is bound to an element in `View`, usually takes value from
some model class instance and when the value is updated in the `View`, the property propagates the change of the value into the underlying model class instance.

However in case when you have a property in `ViewModel` returning e.g. an `ObservableCollection` that is constructed from values
from the model, the change of the values in the `View` only changes the values in the ObservableCollection. It does not propagate the change of values into the underlying model class instance.

So for example, you have a modal dialog (= the `View`), you display this dialog together with its datacontext (=`ViewModel`) and the ViewModel contains an instance of a model class. 
Now

- **situation A)** you have a ViewModel that has only properties that return non-collection types (int, string ...), when you close the dialog 
  you know that the model class instance has the updated values.
- **situation B)** you have a ViewModel that has a property exposing an ObservableCollection<>, when you close the dialog, the model class
  instance does not contain the updated values.

**What is the common pattern/practice of dealing with this?**
I thought you could have a method that writes the data that are present in `ViewModel` into the Model instance and call this method when the dialog closes. But this seems unnatural to me with the philosophy of MVVM and WPF so far.

Please keep in mind that the before mentioned example is just an example. This applies to any View-ViewModel-Model interaction in general.

---

In case someone didn't understand what I was trying to describe:

Let's have a model class

```
public enum A
{
    A1,
    A2,
    A3    
}

public class MyModel
{
    private float[][] array;

    public MyModel()
    {
        array = new float[Enum.GetNames(typeof(A)).Length][];
        foreach (A a in EnumUtil.GetValues<A>())
        {
            array[(int) a] = new float[3]; // any number, really, but it will be referenced later in text
        }
    }

    public A EnumerationA { get; set; }
    public float this[A a, int b]
    {
        get
        {
            return array[(int) a][b];
        }
        set
        {
            array[(int)a][b] = value;
        }
    }        
    public float[] ArraySlice
    {
        get
        {
            return array[(int) EnumerationA];
        }
    }
}
```

and a ViewModel class

```
public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private MyModel _myModel;
    private ObservableCollection<float>[] _tmp = new ObservableCollection<float>[Enum.GetNames(typeof(A)).Length];

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        // in constructor we will add 3 values to each collection
    }

    public A EnumerationA
    {
        get
        {
            return _myModel.EnumerationA;
        }
        set
        {
            if (Enum.Equals(_myModel.EnumerationA, value) == false)
            {
                _myModel.EnumerationA = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("EnumerationA");
                RaisePropertyChanged("ArraySlice");
            }
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<float> ArraySlice
    {
        get
        {
            return _tmp[(int) EnumerationA];
        }
    }       
}
```

The ArraySlice can be bound to anything DataGrid etc....
So in this example, when user is done, the values stored in the array of ObservableCollections are not saved in the model instance. 
However if instead of the property returning ObservableCollection, we had three properties, each returning float, the values would easily be propagated into the underlying model class instance right in the property setter.

Preferably I would welcome an idea / solution that wouldn't require me to do anything once the interaction between View / ViewModel / Model ends.

Comment: @Sheridan - Hello, you told me I could notify you about this question - [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20067578/wpf-datagrid-listview-bind-to-array-mvvm#comment30020943_20071900)

Comment: I don't get something in your *situation A*, why do you say that simple properties are directly propagated to model? Are you saving the value back to the model in each setter in the ViewModel?

Comment: @Alejandro Yes, for simple values I don't have a field in ViewModel that backs up the ViewModel property. I usually simply use the model's field/property. Therefore in the setter i write directly back to the model. I thought this was the correct way to do it. Is there anything wrong with it?

Comment: I don't like that approach really but is of course possible. Problem is that it bypasses any chances of validation of user input, which may leave at some points the model in an invalid state, where it may even throw exceptions for sufficiently complex properties and combinations. Also, you don't get an easy way to cancel the user edits if he wants to do so. My preference is to either map everything to ViewModel, then map it back or use a DTO and bind to that, then convert it back to the model. Another option would be to subscribe to `CollectionChanged` and there add/remove from model